# MySQL: Sum 2 column together, condition based on 2 other fields group by user into a new field

Tags: mysql, sql, select, sum, conditional-statements

I know, the title can be confusing, I wrote it and even I am not sure that it really means what I want so bear with me...

Here is what I have as a result of several records in my table (lets call it charges):

```
ID  employee_name      amountA amountB  valueA value B  billing_date
1   Luc                 0.15    5.00       0       0    2018-02-06
2   Luc                 0.00    2.85       0       0    2018-02-06
3   Luc                 0.00    3.15       0       1    2018-02-06
4   Anny               15.00    0.00       1       0    2018-02-06
5   Anny                0.00    0.35       0       0    2018-02-06
6   Anny               10.25    0.00       0       0    2018-02-06
```

What I want is a SELECT statement that will return me this (the above) added of a new column that is the SUM(amountA) + SUM(amountB) if both valueA and valueB are equal to 0. So as this:

```
ID  employee_name      amountA amountB  valueA value B  billing_date   total
1   Luc                 0.15    5.00       0       0    2018-02-06      8.00
2   Luc                 0.00    2.85       0       0    2018-02-06      8.00
3   Luc                 0.00    3.15       0       1    2018-02-06      8.00
4   Anny               15.00    0.00       1       0    2018-02-06     10.60 
5   Anny                0.00    0.35       0       0    2018-02-06     10.60
6   Anny               10.25    0.00       0       0    2018-02-06     10.60
```

As you see, the date range must be taken into account as well. I have read many post on this, see how to do it if I only want 1 record per employee with the added "total" column but I can't seems to be able to generate the above.

All is in the same database.  So far my SQL statement looked like this (based on Gordon Linoff help below):

```
select c.*,
   (select sum(c2.amountA) + sum(c2.amountB)
    from charges c2
    where c2.employee_name = c.employee_name and c2.valueA = 0 and c2.valueB = 0 and c2.billing_date <= '2018-02-06' and c2.billing_date >= '2018-02-06' 
   ) as total from charges c WHERE employee_name LIKE '%' and c.billing_date <= '2018-02-06' and c.billing_date >= '2018-02-06' 
order BY `c`.`employee_name` ASC
```

Now this is getting close to what I want, the last issue is that if it happens that for a date range I get nothing for a specific employee_name (so the result should be 0.00) I get NULL as so:

```
ID  employee_name      amountA amountB  valueA value B  billing_date   total
1   Luc                 0.15    5.00       1       0    2018-02-06      NULL
2   Luc                 0.00    2.85       1       0    2018-02-06      NULL
3   Luc                 0.00    3.15       0       1    2018-02-06      NULL
4   Anny               15.00    0.00       1       0    2018-02-06      10.60 
5   Anny                0.00    0.35       0       0    2018-02-06      10.60
6   Anny               10.25    0.00       0       0    2018-02-06      10.60
```

Is there a way to pre-defined "total" with zero or some kind of condition to apply on "total" that if it is NULL, show 0?

Answer (score 0):

One method uses a correlated subquery:

```
select c.*,
       (select sum(c2.amountA) + sum(c2.amountB)
        from charges c2
        where c2.employee_name = c.employee_name and c2.valueA = 0 and c2.valueB = 0
       ) as total
from charges c;
```

EDIT:

If you don't want `NULL`, just use `coalesce()`:

```
select c.*,
       coalesce((select sum(c2.amountA) + sum(c2.amountB)
                 from charges c2
                 where c2.employee_name = c.employee_name and c2.valueA = 0 and c2.valueB = 0
                ), 0
               ) as total
from charges c;
```

Comment: This one is the closest so far. But with some specification added by me I get an different problem...see new post.

Answer (score 0):

You could join the subquery for total

```
select m.* , t.total 
from my_table m
left join (

    select employee_name, sum(amountA + amountB) total 
    from my_table
    where valueA = 0 and value B = 0 
    group by employee_name 
) t  on m.employee_name = t.example
```

Comment: Sadly, this one gives me repeated result record for the same user and when I use  LIKE '%' for the employee_name, I get the ssame total for all.  Thanks for trying...

Comment: You comment seems not related  to the sample you provided .. if you are using others sample is impossible suggest a valid solution for you

Answer (score 0):

Finally, the use of COALESCE fixed my last problem as so:

```
select c.*,
coalesce((select sum(c2.amountA) + sum(c2.amountB) from charges c2
         where c2.employee_name = c.employee_name and c2.valueA = 0 and c2.valueB = 0 
         and c2.billing_date <= '2018-02-06' and c2.billing_date >= '2018-02-06'),'0.00') as total 
from charges c WHERE employee_name LIKE '%' and c.billing_date <= '2018-02-06' and c.billing_date >= '2018-02-06' 
order BY `c`.`employee_name` ASC
```

Thanks everyone!!!